# Script to convert images in subfolders to individual PDF's

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I am looking for a way of automating a manual conversion of directories containing images (jpgs & pngs) into PDF's.  For example ..

I currently use the following command to achieve what I want but I have to do this manually for each directory so it can become a little time consuming, etc

```
convert DIRECTORY1/*jpg DIRECTORY1.pdf
convert DIRECTORY2/*jpg DIRECTORY2.pdf
convert DIRECTORY3/*png DIRECTORY3.pdf
```

I would like a way of converting all the directories in the current location to individual pdf files at once.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The most upvoted solution in the question I linked to uses imagemagick convert.

Answer (score 0):

Something like will walk in the tree, extract directories and do the conversion. Be aware this can have problems with directory names which contain space or special symbols:

```
for i in `find . -type d`
do
convert "${i}/*jpg" "${i}/*png" ${i}.pdf
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and suggestion.  I seem to get the following sytax error when running the script ..

./test.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/test.sh: line 2: `do

Comment: @BenRobins your script likely has Windows-style (CRLF) line endings - check your editor settings and make sure it is set to Unix style (LF)

Comment: Hi there, I used GNU nano to make it so it should be good.  I have tried re making the script several times but still get this..

'./test.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r'''

Comment: @BenRobins, you can test with `od -ax` if there is windows-style EOL. Or run dos2unix on the script

Comment: Ah thanks, dos2unix seems to have solved that issue. Running the script gives the following errors..

Comment: convert: unable to open image `find . -type d/*jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.

Comment: convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.

Comment: @BenRobins, check if you have backticks around `find . -type d` command

Comment: Ah thank you.   Script works wonderfully!

It prints the following errors but still manages to successfully create the PDFs

Comment: convert: unable to open image `./*png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.

Comment: convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.

Comment: convert: no images defined `..pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.

Comment: @BenRobins, it can be edited to add png images also. But please edit your questions accordingly

Comment: Apologies, I will edit my main question above.  Thank you.

Comment: The script could probably benefit from a `shopt -s nullglob` to stop `"${i}/*jpg"` from being substituted literally when there are no .jpg files in a particular directory (that's likely what's causing many of the errors)

Comment: @steeldriver, as I am not familiar with shopt feel free to edit the answer :)

Comment: I have noticed that the script seems to change something about the images once in the PDF, I believe that it is resizing the images during the conversion?  

Would there be a way of making it so that it is simply binding all images into PDF without making any changes to the images at all?